# Ping Connection Pool failed for jmspool. Could not create connection. Please check the server.log for more details

Tags: glassfish

I'm GlassFish 3.1.2, ActiveMQ 5.1.1 and ActiveMQ 5.8 resource adapter (activemq-rar-5.1.1) I have created a GlassFish cluster with 2 instances. I reference http://geertschuring.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/how-to-connect-glassfish-3-to-activemq-5/ to assist with the initial deployment/configuration of activemq resource adapter After configuring the Connector Connection Pool via GlassFish Admin Console and enable Ping. When Ping is executed an error occurs: Ping Connection Pool for jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory is Failed. Ping failed Exception - This pool is not registered with the runtime environment : jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory Please check the server.log for more details. Ping failed Exception - This pool is not registered with the runtime environment : jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory Please check the server.log for more details.

appreciate for your replay

Comment: Please check the server.log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

by any chance is your glassfish instance in a cluster?. In our case it was failing with the same error message, and we figured out that if the instance is in a cluster, it doesn´t work. Though it works if it is not in a cluster.

We verified this also by checking in the activemq admin console the the consumers were active and receiving message, even if the ping command was failing.